# Any cocomplete category with a dense small full subcategory is complete?

Tags: ct.category-theory

Hello,

I with to consider the following statement:

If $C$ is a cocomplete category having a dense small full subcategory $D$, then $C$ is complete.

(a full subcategory $D$ is dense in $C$ if every element of $C$ is canonical colimit of elements of $D$...)

I think I know how to prove it (I give proof below), and I want someone to reassure me that this statement is true exactly as stated, as it seems a little bit surprising.

Proof sketch:

Consider the functor $Y : C \to psh(D)$, where $psh(D)$ denotes the category of presheaves on $D$ (Yoneda functor, i.e. $Y(X)(A) = Hom (A, X)$). $D$ being dense in $C$ is equivalent to this functor being fully faithful. Futhermore, we have a functor $F: psh(D) \to C$, namely, the one which extends the inclusion $D \to C$ by cocontinuity (as presheaf categories have the property of being free cocompletions: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/free+cocompletion). Then one can see that $Y$ is right adjoint to $F$. So this renders $C$ as reflective subcategory of $psh(D)$ ( http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/reflective+subcategory). Now, $psh(D)$ is complete, and so every reflective subcategory of it. hence, $C$ is complete.

Thank you,
Sasha

Comment: Perhaps you should fill in the condition in your title.

Comment: "namely, the one which extends the inclusion $D \to C$ by cocontinuity." Can you explain that in more detail?

Comment: As Martin says, you should revise the title.  Right now, it looks like you're asking "what condition should I add to cocompleteness to guarantee completeness?", but instead you're asking "Is it true that any cocomplete category with a dense small full subcategory is complete?"

Comment: Thank you for your comments; I tried to fix the question according to them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a well-known theorem, you can find it for example in [Abstract and concrete categories - the Joy of Cats](http://katmat.math.uni-bremen.de/acc/acc.pdf), Theorem 12.12. The proof there uses that a cocomplete category with a weakly terminal object has a terminal object (the preparation for the Freyd's adjoint functor theorem).

Answer (score 7):

As Martin says, this is true.  I like to think of this implication as factoring through a third notion: any [total category](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/total+category) is complete (and more than complete), whereas any cocomplete category with a small dense subcategory is total.

Comment: Well this is included in Sasha's proof, right?

Comment: Not exactly; it looks to me like he proved that the embedding of C into the presheaf category of its small dense subcategory D has a left adjoint, rather than that the embedding of C into its own presheaf category has a left adjoint.  Close, though.

Comment: @Mike: Well, this is basically contained in his proof. You just have compose with the geometric morphism $(i_*,i^*),$ where $i:D \hookrightarrow C$ is the inclusion. Since $i$ is full and faithful, so is $i_*.$

Comment: Like I said: close.  (-:

Comment: For future readers, I'd like to point out a reference to this fact: corollary 6.5, "A survey of totality for enriched and ordinary categories", by Max Kelly, where it is worked out in the enriched context.

Answer (score 1):

A more direct proof:

A limit of a diagram  $(A_j)_{j\in J}$ is the colimit of the following $\pi: \mathcal{D}_A\to \mathcal{C}$:  Objects of $\mathcal{D}_A$ are the $(D, \pi_D)$ with $D\in \mathcal{D}$ with a (natural) cone $\pi_{D,j}: D \to A_j\ j\in J$, the morphisms $(D, \pi_D)\to (D', \pi_{D'})$ are  morphims $D\to D'$ coherents by $\pi_D$ and $\pi_{D'}$ and $\pi: \mathcal{D}_A\to \mathcal{C}: (D, \pi_D) \mapsto D$ .